# Simplest way to check the type of a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function type(arg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg).slice(8, -1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Is there any flaw in the above code to check the type?

Comment: What is wrong with `typeof`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: I think you should define what you would class as a "flaw"

Comment: I’d say the main flaw in this approach is that you assume that the result of the toString method of any given object that you might pass into that function would be the exact same text in every given browser …

Answer (score 2):

Really depends on what you want the function to return. There are slight differences between `typeof` and `type()`.

```
> type('wat')
"string"
> typeof 'wat'
"string"
> type(window)
"global"
> typeof window
"object"
> type(document)
"htmldocument"
> typeof document
"object"
```

Comment: Sorry - too quick to vote. Before your edit it really didn't look like an answer. Vote retracted.

Comment: No worries, shouldn't have typed the response, then `Ctrl+A/V` the console output. I'm not a smart man.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. there is a keyword `typeof`

e.g

```
var abc = typeof variablename;
```

here abc will contain type of variable